# Controlling the activation of the default transition in viewmodels

Tags: javascript, transition, durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

My question is quite simple and needs no special explanation.

*In Durandal, is it possible to control whether or not to use transition when switching from/to a viewmodel?*

The reason why I want to be able to deactivate the animation is as follows:

I have a search form module `quicksearch.js` in my shell/masterpage that is accessible from anywhere. What it does is validate the input and then simply redirect to the results page `results.js` passing the search parameters in an URL after hash. The `results.js` takes care of querying the server.

When the `quicksearch.js` module is used while on a page other than `results.js`, the animation is triggered and it's desired behavior. However, when on `results.js` and using `quicksearch.js`, the only thing that changes in URL is the parameter string (module name right after the hash is left unchanged). Still, this goes through all the lifecycle of activating `results.js` again, with animating from `results.js` to `results.js` and that looks pretty bad.

So, *is there any way to, under a condition, prevent Durandal from animating the content and just compose and bind the view?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to control the transition process from my viewmodel, I doubt there is a way to do it.

Yet, the reason I asked was that I wanted to prevent Durandal from animating when navigating to the current page with different hash query string (changing this query string does trigger the navigation). The solution was to create a custom transition and to check whether the target view id is or isn't the same as the current view id. rely relied on

```
context.activeView.dataset.view === context.child.dataset.view;
```

where `context.activeView` is the currently attached view and `context.child` is the view that is about to be bound. Then, if these ids are different, I trigger the animation and if not, I simply hide `context.activeView` and show the other.

That's it for this case